# Post request to database associated with primary and foreign key in web api using Entity Framework

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a database with three tables  with primary and foreign key association .

I am using Web API and Entity Framework to auto generate methods. I have been successful doing that. But I want to insert into a table with foreign key separately.

Currently, I am able to get a `JSON` object for the main table which has primary key and navigation properties to the table with a foreign key.
[image]

I have created the web api using auto generate read write action methods like .
[image]

I am able to access the json object for floors database and accordingly for Meter and Router . So , I have a post method "/api/floorinfoes" with POST .
But , what to do , if i want to insert separately into RouterInfo  table and MeterInfo table .Eg: If i want to insert one row in MeterInfoes table, then how to proceed with that .

Comment: Could you add some code so we know what you have done and may be able to help? Thanks

Comment: I have added the snapshot of database and web api .I think , it will help you to understand my query .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert one row in MeterInfoes Table.

```
public class MeterInfo
{
        [Key]
        public int MeterId { get; set; }
        public string MeterName { get; set; }

        public int? FloorId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FloorId")]
        public FloorInfo FloorInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Add your entities to DbContext, if not done already

```
public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{

        public DbSet<FloorInfo> FloorInfos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MeterInfo> MeterInfos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RouterInfo> RouterInfos { get; set; }
}
```

Create a new controller MeterInfoController or auto generate using scaffolding

```
public class MeterInfoController : ApiController
{

    public IHttpActionResult Post(MeterInfo meterInfo)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

         db.MeterInfo.Add(meterInfo);
         db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(meterInfo);
    }
}
```

To consume this endpoint, for example:

```
Url : /api/MeterInfo
```

If you know the FloorId

```
   Post Data : {"MeterId": 1, "MeterName" : "Test" , "FloorId" : 10 }
```

If you do not know the FloorId, but make sure FloorId in MeterInfo is nullable

```
 Post Data:  {"MeterId": 1, "MeterName" : "Test"}
```

I think the answer is to auto generate API Controllers for both MeterInfo and RouterInfo.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Does it mean that we have to create separate API for each table in the database in order to perform. CRUD operations??

Comment: You told that ::"If you do not know the FloorId, but make sure FloorId in MeterInfo is nullable" we can not have floorid  as nullable as it is the   primary key for other table with foreign key reference in the current table . Do we have to apply condition like insert row only if floorid is already present in floorinfo table .

Comment: Technically, you don't need to create separate API, you could create another method like PostMeterInfo, but making it separate is much more cleaner.If FloorId is a required property then, yes check if it has a value.